# String processing during table creation and inserting from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

I have a table that contains file paths, like so:

```
--------------------
|Files             |
--------------------
|path nvarchar(500)|
--------------------
```

I want to split it into two tables, one containing unique directories and one containing filenames:

```
---------------------------
|Files                    |
---------------------------
|filename    nvarchar(255)|
|directoryId int          |
---------------------------

---------------------------
|Directories              |
---------------------------
|id          int          |
|path        nvarchar(255)|
---------------------------
```

So for example if an entry originally was "C:/folder/file.jpg", I want an entry in Directories for "C:/folder/", and the entry in Files would be updated to have "file.jpg" for the filename and the directory id of the new entry in Directories.

(In case you're wondering at this point, the reason I need to do this is because I need to keep track of some information at the directory level.)

Is there a good way to do this in a T SQL script?

Comment: While waiting for someone with the full script, you might want to take a look at `CHARINDEX` function in T-SQL at http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms186323.aspx

Comment: You should also take a look at reverse string function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx

Comment: I had seen those functions, but was hoping there was some more advanced string processing hiding somewhere. Guess not! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @FULL VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @FILE VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @directoryId INT

DECLARE curs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT path FROM FILES_1

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @FULL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @FILE = right(@FULL, charindex('/',reverse(@FULL))-1)
    SET @PATH = left(@FULL, len(@FULL) - charindex('/',reverse(@FULL))+1)
    SET @directoryId = SELECT ID from Directories WHERE  path = @PATH

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        IF @directoryId IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Directories VALUES (@PATH)
            SET @directoryId = @@IDENTITY
        END

        INSERT INTO  Files VALUES ( @FILE,@directoryId)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0 ROLLBACK

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Changed to a cursor!

Comment: Where are you declaring @filename?

Comment: copy and paste fail, i nicked you string manipulations since they were a bit neater than mine!

Comment: No Problem! :) just trying to avoid a Must declare the scalar variable "@filename"

Comment: Looks great, and makes total sense. Will try it out tomorrow. One small thing -- instead of creating a new table for files, I want to update the previous Files table to have the new filename and directoryId instead of the old path. Would I have to run two cursors, one for FileId (which I omitted in my schema above, but it's there) and one for path? I'm pretty new to SQL scripting beyond basic queries.

Comment: You can update the cursor as you iterate through it, just remove the fast forward part.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @filename varchar(500)

set @filename = 'C:/Folder/file.jpg'

select right(@filename, charindex('/',reverse(@filename))-1)

select left(@filename, len(@filename) - charindex('/',reverse(@filename))+1)
```

This will be the whole conversion:

```
insert into Directories ([path])
select distinct
    left([path], len([path]) - charindex('/',reverse([path]))+1) as [path]
from files

select 
    d.id,
    right(f.[path], charindex('/',reverse(f.[path]))-1)
from files f
inner join directories d
    on left(f.[path], len(f.[path]) - charindex('/',reverse(f.[path]))+1) = d.[path]
```

I was not sure the real names of the tables because you have two Files tables in your schema.